# Python: How to pair a string with a variable that's equal to a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I pair a string with a variable that's equal to a number?
For example

```
king = random.randint(150 , 300)

attackred = str(input("who would you like to attack with"))

if (attackred == "king"):

    redking = ("king")
```

in line 1, I make the king variable an integer within 150-300
in line 2, I ask the typer who he would like to attack with, king is just an example, there are multiple options
in line 3 and 4, I created an if statement so when the user types in ("king") into line 2 it would be paired with the redking variable which is a number so I can use it later in my code.

Comment: The type of data structure you are looking for is called a dictionary, or a `dict` in Python. For example `d = {'king': random.randint(150 , 300)}` you can then access the value for `'king'` with something like `print(d['king'])` - you would probably do well to watch or read a few tutorials on Python before asking more questions though, this is so basic that you'll find people will point you at the manual and tutos anyway.

Comment: use Hashtable/Hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood it correctly, you want to "associate" the user typed string with the number that was generated in the line 1 (i.e. variable king)

You can use a dictionary in that case. Use something like:

```
ref_dictionary = {}
king = random.randint(150 , 300)
attackred = str(input("who would you like to attack with"))

ref_dictionary[attackred] = king

if (attackred == "king"):
    redking = ref_dictionary[attackred]
```